# Simplifying expression in summation notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, summation

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to simplify this expression, if at all possible? Thank you.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} {n\choose i} (-1)^{i+1} 2^{n^2+2(n-i)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Observe you have
\begin{align}
-2^{n^2} \sum^n_{i=1} \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i 4^{n-i}
\end{align}

Comment: ... and recognize a binomial expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) up to to the first term.